# Scroll bottom hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for my english. I am learning)
So, my question:
When i scroll bottom i need to hide div, but scroll did not work. When my div is hide, scroll will work.
I am trying do next:
JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var n = 0;
    var deleteBlocks;
    $('.trigger').on('click', function(event) {
        $('header').addClass('trans');
        $('header').addClass('hidden');
        n=1;
    });
    var h = $(window).height();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop()==0) {
            if ($("header").hasClass("hidden")) {
                $("header").removeClass("hidden");
                n=0;
                deleteBlocks = new TweenMax('',0,{delay: 1, onComplete:function() {                 
                    $('.text,.trigger').removeClass('disnone');;
                }});
            }   
        } else {
            $('header').addClass('hidden');
            $('header').addClass('trans');
            $('.text,.trigger').addClass('disnone');
            if (n==0) {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: '1px'}, 0);
                n=1;
            }
        }   
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #012345;
    text-align: center;
}
header {
    background: url(../img/slide1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.text {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30%;
}
.trigger {
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 45%;
}
.trans {
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    transition:1s;  
}
.disnone {
    display: none;
}

.hidden {
    color: red;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head class="no-js" lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Исчезающая шапка</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class='header'>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="text tr">
                Пробная версия 1.0
            </div>
            <button class='trigger tr'>CLICK FOR HIDDEN</button>
        </div>      
    </header>
    <section>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
        adadasdasdasdasd<br>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

But it's not than i want to get.

Comment: can you add the html too?

Comment: Could you try to reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle?

Comment: my code don't work on JSFiddle. But if you create 3 file on your computer and copy my code, it's work.
https://jsfiddle.net/43tqhkfv/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to have an introduction pane which slides away when you press the button and reveals the content which wasn't accessible before. To achieve this, you can do something like this:

```js
$("button.trigger").on("click", function() {
  $("section").show();
  $("header").slideUp();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
  background: #012345;
  text-align: center;
}
header {
  background: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30%;
}
.trigger {
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: 45%;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class='header'>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text tr">
      Пробная версия 1.0
    </div>
    <button class='trigger tr'>CLICK FOR HIDDEN</button>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="hidden">
  First Line
  <br>
  <span style="height: 1500px; display: block;">spacing</span>
  Last Line
</section>
```

What I did here is I set the intro pane (header) to `display: none;` at page load and show it at runtime when pressing the button as well as sliding up the header. Scrolling should therefore be disabled by default, as there is nothing to scroll there.